# styled-components media queries not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I am using styled components to style my react project, components are working fine, but for some reason media queries are not applied. Here's a snippet that works when using regular css:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Block = styled.div `
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: #DAD870;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        width: 42%;
        min-width: 158px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        width: 40%;
        min-width: 148px;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use react but it looks like you are trying to use @media inside of an element, I don't think that works, instead try something like:

```
div{
   min-width: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   div{
     width: 42%;
     min-width: 158px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
   div{
     width: 40%;
     min-width: 148px;
   }
}
```

I don't know how to show you like the way you did it but basically you need to declare it separately, hope it helped.

Comment: That is in regular css, but in styled components you do it inside of component, if I wasn't clear this isn't css file it's js, but I got css file working using these media queries